# Uploading Multiple Files via Admin and Model in Django

Tags: python, django, multiple-file-upload

I'm building a very basic application (my first Django app). And I wanted the user to add a book in the database. So, I have one model that adds a book, along with its Name and an Image (Book Cover).

This is working just fine. Now, I wanted to upload chapters for this book and a chapter will have multiple pages, so multiple files (say, .pdf files). I made another class for the chapters and have linked this class via ForeginKey.

I looked over a few answers here on SO, reddit and some random blogs and all of them seem to be out of date, old or not working.

I'm adding all this information by using the default admin view that we get in the Django. I'm not sure how to go about this now. I don't want multiple FileField, because the number of pages in a chapter is unknown. Any hints?

My models.py is like this :

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

def book_upload_location(instance, filename):
    return '{}/{}'.format(instance.book_name, filename)

def book_chapter_upload_location(instance, filename):
    # /media/book_Name/Chapter_Number/
    return '{}/{}/{}'.format(instance.book.book_name, instance.chapter_number, filename)

class book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    book_description = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    book_author = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    book_genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book_image = models.FileField(upload_to=book_upload_location)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.book_name) + " ( " + str(self.pk) + ")"

class bookChapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(book, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # Let's delete all the chapters related to a particular book, if book is deleted.
    chapter_title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    chapter_number = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    chapter_images = models.FileField(upload_to=book_chapter_upload_location, widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.book.book_name) + " - " + " C" + str(self.chapter_number)
```

EDIT : So, as @neverwalkaloner suggested, I changed my code to do the "Workaround" and I'm getting new error.

`AttributeError: 'bookChapterFiles' object has no attribute 'book'`

My Models.py

from django.db import models
    from django import forms

```
def book_upload_location(instance, filename):

    return '{}/{}'.format(instance.book_name, filename)


def book_chapter_upload_location(instance, filename):

    return '{}/{}/{}'.format(instance.book.book_name, instance.chapter.chapter_number, filename)


class book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    book_description = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    book_author = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    book_genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book_image = models.FileField(upload_to=book_upload_location)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.book_name) + " ( " + str(self.pk) + ")"


class bookChapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(book,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # Let's delete all the chapters related to a particular book, if book is deleted.
    print("My book : %s" % book)
    chapter_title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    chapter_number = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    chapter_volume = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default=0)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # chapter_images = models.FileField(upload_to=book_chapter_upload_location)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.book.book_name) + " - " + "V" + str(self.chapter_volume) + " C" + str(self.chapter_number)


class bookChapterFiles(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(bookChapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chapter_images = models.FileField(upload_to=book_chapter_upload_location)
```

My Admin.py :

from django.contrib import admin
    from books.models import book, bookChapter, bookChapterFiles

```
# class PageFileInline(admin.TabularInline):
#     model = bookChapter
#
#
# class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
#     inlines = [PageFileInline, ]

class ChapterInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = bookChapterFiles


class bookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ChapterInline,
    ]


admin.site.register(bookChapter, bookAdmin)

admin.site.register(book)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attribute error seems to come from your naming of classes and attributes. 
Specifically inside your model bookChapter:

```
class bookChapter(models.Model):
book = models.ForeignKey(book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Change the name of your book model to "Book" instead of "book".

I'm not sure how well django will handle your naming conventions. To me it looks like that's the problem. You are using lower case letters for you model "book" and your bookChapter's attribute "book", and referencing them both within the class. Even if it's working, it's confusing!

Change this:

```
class book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    book_description = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    book_author = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    book_genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book_image = models.FileField(upload_to=book_upload_location)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.book_name) + " ( " + str(self.pk) + ")"


class bookChapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

To this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=book_upload_location)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) + " ( " + str(self.pk) + ")"


class BookChapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You should really consider using upper casing for your class name. 
You are calling your book model "book", but since it's a class you should call it "Book". 
The attribute names of the book-model are also redundant. prefixing "book_" to a name, description and an author field on a book class just makes you have to type "book" twice. 
For example:

```
book.book_name()
```

It should be:

```
Book.name()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [AdminInline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects). Your admin.py should look something like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import book, bookChapter

class ChapterInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = bookChapter

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ChapterInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(book, BookAdmin)
```

**UPDATE**

I think new error is in `book_chapter_upload_location` function. You are calling `instance.book` there:

```
return '{}/{}/{}'.format(instance.book.book_name, instance.chapter.chapter_number, filename)
```

But bookChapterFiles dont have `book` attribute. Try to change it:

```
return '{}/{}/{}'.format(instance.chapter.book.book_name, instance.chapter.chapter_number, filename)
```

Comment: showing `<class 'book.admin.BookAdmin'>: (admin.E104) 'book.models.bookChapter' must inherit from 'InlineModelAdmin'.`

Comment: @Xonshiz updated answer. Try to replace bookChapter with ChapterInline in 'inlines' list.

Comment: This is adding the bookChapter on the same page of `Book` and it's giving me multiple fields to upload multiple files. I want to open bookChapter separately and have one button to upload multiple files. This happening right now : http://i.imgur.com/hDRfJwN.png

Comment: @Xonshiz Oh, my answer is not what you want than. I don't know is what you are looking for possible or not. But if you will not find better solution you can just add another model `ChapterFile` with foreign key to bookChapter and filefield. And then use method from my answer to upload multiple files from chapter page.

Comment: did same things, updated the code and got a new error :/

Comment: ah thanks.. this is nice workaround. But, I'm still waiting for just one FileField to take multiple selections. Thanks for this though!